# AJAX post data from cloned forms in one submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am posting multiple forms in one submit for a 'Refer a Friend' page. There is initially just 2 forms, one for the referrer and one for a referral. Users can 'add' more referral forms by clicking a plus sign which clone()s the referral form and append it to the container.

```
<div class="form-wrap">
  <form id="referrer-form" role="form" action="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>" method="post" >
    inputs...
  </form>
  <form id="first-ref" class="referral-form" role="form" action="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>" method="post">
    inputs...
  </form>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
  <a id="plus" class="btn btn-primary" href=""></a>
  <a id="minus" class="btn btn-danger" href=""></a>
  <button id="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg form-control">SUBMIT</button>
</div>
```

With my current jQuery, the 2 forms that are loaded with the page markup post just fine. However, the ones that have been clone()d are not posting. All the attributes appear the same.

// AJAX post on each form

```
    var form = $('form');

    $("#submit").click(function () {
        $('#referrer', '#referrer-form').val('what is posted to leadsource field');
        $(form).each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("id") != "referrer-form") {
                $('#referrer', this).val('Referred by: ' + $('#referrer-form #name').val());
            }
            var formData = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $(form).attr('action'),
                data: formData
            });
        });
        alert("form submitted");
        $('form input').val('');
    });

    $("#plus").click(function () {
        $("#first-ref").clone().appendTo(".form-wrap");
        $(".referral-form").last().attr('id', '');
        $(".referral-form").last().find('input').val('');
        load_phoneMask_js();
    });

    $("#minus").click(function () {
        $(".referral-form").last().remove();
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's `clone()` has an argument in the form of `.clone( [withDataAndEvents ] )`, meaning if you want to keep data and events, you pass `true`

```
$("#first-ref").clone(true).appendTo(".form-wrap");
```

And make sure you get those forms inside the event handler

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
    var form = $('form');

    ... etc
```